# deploying officejs fabric react word add in

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, office-js

I have a word add in written in typescript using Officejs and office-ui-fabric-react. Everything works fine with the server running locally. I'd like to deploy into AWS S3 with Cloudfront. I'm building with npm run build, and npm run deploy (using deploy command "aws --profile profile-name s3 sync dist/ s3://bucketname".  Static web site hosting is enabled in the S3 bucket.  All files from the dist directory are seen in the bucket. After inserting the add in into Word with a manifest.xml file that points to the cloudfront endpoint I'm getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined". The same error occurs when I point directly to the S3 static web endpoint. To see if I've missed anything I deployed a generic create-react-app using the steps above and it runs fine. I'm assuming that the problem lies with my webpack config so I've included that here (common, and prod).  I'd be happy to include anything else that's needed.  I'm also open to other deployment options if using AWS is causing the problem.

webpack.common.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const package = require('../package.json');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const build = (() => {
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    return {
        name: package.name,
        version: package.version,
        timestamp: timestamp,
        author: package.author
    };
})();

const entry = {
    vendor: [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'core-js',
        'office-ui-fabric-react'
    ],
    app: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        './index.tsx',
    ],
    'function-file': '../function-file/function-file.ts'
};

const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
            'react-hot-loader/webpack',
            'ts-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        use: {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
                name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
            }
        }
    }
];

const output = {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
};

const WEBPACK_PLUGINS = [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({ banner: `${build.name} v.${build.version} (${build.timestamp}) © ${build.author}` }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        ENVIRONMENT: JSON.stringify({
            build: build
        })
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
            postcss: [
                autoprefixer({ browsers: ['Safari >= 8', 'last 2 versions'] }),
            ],
            htmlLoader: {
                minimize: true
            }
        }
    })
];

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('./src'),
    entry,
    output,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.scss', '.css', '.html']
    },
    module: {
        rules,
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'async',
          minChunks: Infinity,
          name: 'vendor'
        }
      },
    plugins: [
        ...WEBPACK_PLUGINS,
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'letterConfig',
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './index.html',
            chunks: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'letterConfig',
            filename: 'function-file/function-file.html',
            template: '../function-file/function-file.html',
            chunks: ['function-file']
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: '../assets',
                ignore: ['*.scss'],
                to: 'assets',
            }
        ])
    ]
};
```

webpack.prod.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'development';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    externals: {
        'react': 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
    },

    performance: {
        hints: "warning"
    },

    optimization: {
        minimize: true
      }
});
```

index.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { initializeIcons } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons';

import App from './components/App';

import './styles.less';
import 'office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.min.css';

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = 'letterConfig';

const render = (Component) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('container')
    );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.initialize = () => {
    console.log('init');
    isOfficeInitialized = true;
    render(App);
};

/* Initial render showing a progress bar */
render(App);

if ((module as any).hot) {
    (module as any).hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
        const NextApp = require('./components/App').default;
        render(NextApp);
    });
}
```

Comment: You should be able to host an add-in on any service. Some questions: What are the exact steps that lead to the error and where do you see the error? Are you using `Office.initialize` or `Office.onReady`? Is the React bootstrapping code inside the `initialize` or `onReady`? How are you sideloading the manifest?

Comment: I'm seeing the error in the console using office365.  Also, just using the url in a browser shows the same error.   I'm using Office.initialize, and it's bootstrapping there.  I'm uisng insert->Office addins, and uploading the manifest.xml.   I'll include the entire index.tsx file in the original post for clarity.

Comment: I'm still not clear on when/where you see the error. Do you have a ribbon button that opens the add-in a task pane? Is that when it errors? I don't know what "the console using office 365" means. If you comment out the line `render(App)` about 8 lines up from the bottom (not the one inside `Office.initialize`), do you still get the error? Finally, please verify that react and react-dom are in the bundle that you are hosting on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it was looking for a globally defined "React", and so not resolving via an npm module. In the webpack.prod.js file removing the following solved the problem:

```
externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
},
```